# How to store less than / greater than in database

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a common pattern how to store a condition like this in database (postgresql) to then in the easy way fetch these data from DB and in Frontend compare this with our value SE on the Frontend (to get the proper "value"):

```
condition  value
SE < 2     foo
2 ≤ SE <3  bar
3 ≤ SE <4  foo2
4 ≤ SE     bar2
```

Thanks

Comment: If you calculate it in the frontend, store the limits and values in a `json` column in the database.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a good case for a [range column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html)

```
create table data
(
   valid_between int4range,
   value text
);

insert into data (valid_between, value)
values
('(,2)', 'foo'),  -- from infinity to 2
('[2,3)', 'bar'),
('[3,4)', 'foo2'),
('[4,)', 'bar2');  -- from 4 to infinity
```

To find the rows that are valid for the value `3` use the `@>` operator

```
select *
from data
where valid_between @> 3
```

A range column can efficiently be indexed to allow for fast searches.

Comment: Wow! I didn't even know that type of data. I will check Your solution tomorrow and give You response

Comment: This approach is a little bit cumbersome to handle this type of data in Java but not impossible... Personally I use https://vladmihalcea.com/map-postgresql-range-column-type-jpa-hibernate/

Comment: But how to use this special sign @ in my JpaRepository? @Repository
public interface myInterface extends JpaRepository<myEntity, Long> {

 @Query("Select field from myTable where field2@>3")
 String findRequiredActionByNote(@Param("note") Integer note);
} doesn't work: unexpected char: '@'

Comment: @Matley: sorry, no idea. I don't use obfuscation layers like JPA

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to make two columns "lower bound" and "upper bound" like this:

```
LB    UB    ...
-INF  2
2     3
3     5
4     INF
```

Then to query a item by condition, use something like:

```
SELECT value FROM (table) WHERE LB <= SE AND SE < UB;
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the lower bound only and then use `lead` to figure it out on the fly:

```
Threshold  Value
0          foo
2          bar
3          foob
4          barf

with CTE as
  (
  select t1.*, lead(threshold) over(order by threshold) as nextone
  from my_table
  )
select CTE.value
from CTE
where my_value >= threshold
and (my_value < nextone or nextone is null)
```